# Is the figurative sense of "schizophrenia" pejorative towards people with the mental condition?

Tags: word-usage, pejorative-language

"Schizophrenia" has two definitions.  The one I am concerned with is as follows:

> contradictory or antagonistic qualities or attitudes
>   -- ["schizophrenia," *Merriam-Webster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/schizophrenia)

This is a very useful word, but I'm concerned that it might be perceived as pejorative towards individuals with the mental condition, or as inaccurately stereotyping them.  I don't actually know whether this is the case, but I could imagine it being so.

On the other hand, I'm not sure what words I could use instead.  "Inconsistent" and "contradictory" are close, but they do not connote the same level of agency as "schizophrenic."  For example, if an organization is described as "schizophrenic," I imagine a number of departments locked in some kind of bureaucratic war with one another.  A "contradictory organization" doesn't make sense, and an "inconsistent organization" is a much less vivid image for me (maybe it's just incompetently run).  Meanwhile, the word "antagonistic" has agency but lacks direction; it does not denote that the antagonism is inward-facing.

On the *third* hand, this meaning seems entirely compatible with the Greek etymology of "schizophrenia" ("split" + "mind"), which makes it seem less like a twisting of the medical definition and more of a figurative allusion to it.  I'm not sure that makes a practical difference (people will or won't take offense either way), but it's worth noting all the same.

- Is the word "schizophrenic" likely to be taken as pejorative or stereotypical of this group of people?
- If so, what word or phrase should I use instead to convey the same meaning without the pejorative connotations?

Comment: I think this is confirmation bias. A schizophrenic who does not have contradictory attitudes is likely never revealed to be a schizophrenic (as his identities never clash, therefore never leading anyone to evaluate if they're schizophrenic). While schizophrenics may or may not have contradictory attitudes, **known** schizophrenics tend to always have contradicting attitudes (because it's the contradiction that causes them to be identified as schizophrenic). The figurative usage heavily relies on the common perception of schizophrenics, hence the inherent meaning of contradicting attitudes.

Comment: I'm sorry but it is impossible to find a word related to this one that does not have negative connotations. It is a medical word appropriated by others.

Answer (score 1):

If we follow the OED definition:

> A word or expression which by its form or context expresses or implies contempt for the thing named

Then it's not *pejorative* to people with schizophrenia, as they are not "the thing named" in the use.

But that's a matter of the word *pejorative*. It's still insulting to them to use their condition as a term for a negative condition about something else, which is probably more to the point.

If your intention is to avoid ableist language, then such uses are best avoided.

Comment: @TripeHound the term was coined by Eugen Bleuler to describe a medical condition, so the etymology is certainly one of using that medical term in a negative figurative sense. We could argue there's a difference in that it is using an outdated understanding of a medical term in a negative figurative sense, but if you are wishing to avoid insult then that is if anything, worse.

Comment: If that's the case, then you're entirely correct (as I said, I didn't know which came first). I'll delete my speculative comment.

Comment: "Punic" was originally in reference to the Carthaginians, who had a longstanding feud with Rome. English now uses "punic faith" to mean "a promise that one can put no trust in" (based on the Latin _punica fides_). But I would say that someone who uses "punic faith" in English isn't being pejorative towards Carthaginians, he is merely referencing a concept established by the Romans. The concept (untrustworthy faith) is not pejorative, even though its **etymological** origins may be found in pejorative usage.

Comment: Since the figurative use of "schizophrenic" is listed in the OED, that should mean that those who use the word figuratively are not being pejorative, as they are merely referencing a later concept. Similarly, calling a waiter a "server" is not pejorative, even though the etymological origins of "server" come from [the Latin word for "slave"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=serve). Yet no one argues that calling a waiter a "server" is akin to calling him a slave.

Comment: @Flater, for one thing there's a lot more linguistic distance. For another, the Punics are unlikely to be upset by this.

Comment: @Flater what does a figurative sense being in the OED have to do with anything? I never said such senses didn't exist.

Comment: @JonHanna: I wasn't countering your answer, I was adding a further justification. The figurative usage of "schizophrenic" should be taken to refer to the meaning listed in the OED, which is not a pejorative meaning. The existence of the figurative sense in the OED should preclude the assumption that the figurative "schizophrenic" is intended to mean "like a (literal) schizophrenic", which in turn absolves the figurative usage from being intentionally pejorative by the speaker. Hence my justifications: "punic" does not always refer to Carthaginians, "server" does not refer to slaves (anymore).

Comment: @Flater That doesn't follow at all. There is still a strong use of *schizophrenic* to refer to people with a given medical condition, and the way that the figurative sense works is clear to just about anyone. It's not an originally-figurative sense like *server* that now stands quite separate.

Comment: @JonHanna: Though not used as much anymore, [Punic](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/punic) is still listed by its literal meaning. My argument is that the figurative and literal usage of the word is **now** completely separate (even though the figurative usage **used to be** a reference to the literal usage). And since they are now completely separate, that means that one meaning does not inherently refer to the other anymore (which means that the figurative sense is not being pejorative towards the literal meaning). This applies to both "Punic" and "schizophrenic".

Comment: @Flater you're saying that if anyone heard something described as "schizophrenic" they would never consider it as relating to schizophrenia? I'm not going to buy that.

Comment: @JonHanna **Not when it's being used figuratively**. Of course the word by itself is ambiguous between its multiple meanings (that applies to literally any word with more than one definition in the OED), unless the context disambiguates it in any way. The question (= context) is specifically focusing on the **figurative usage** of the word "schizophrenic", and so my statements are inherently focusing on the figurative usage as well.

Comment: The question isn't focusing on the figurative usage, the question is about the **relationship between** the figurative usage and the literal usage.

Answer (score 0):

Jon Hanna, thanks for this
"If we follow the OED definition: A word or expression which by its form or context expresses or implies contempt for the thing named
Then it's not pejorative to people with schizophrenia, as they are not "the thing named" in the use.
... It's still insulting to them to use their condition as a term for a negative condition about something else, which is probably more to the point.
"If your intention is to avoid ableist language, then such uses are best avoided."

In answer to the original question, using the example, "an organization is described as "schizophrenic,"

How about going back to the original Greek etymology: "the organization seems to be of 2 minds"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/412140)

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are asking for general guidance about when it is wise to use figurative language which refers to disabilities suffered by real people.

It depends on what you are doing.

- If you are writing a technical document, you may want to substitute something more directly descriptive, such as

  - *Internally contradictory*,
  - *Inconsistent*
  - *Seemingly random*
  - *Lacking reasoned basis*

  What will be appropriate will depend on what you are trying to say. Depending on your audience, it may be good to avoid figurative language, and instead describe as closely as you can the thing to which you are referring.

  This will be particularly the case if you are writing in a sensitive area, perhaps one with close legal regulation (such as an HR manual) or which is politically fraught.
- If you are writing a novel, you might wish to do the opposite, and instead expand the figurative language, either to add atmosphere, or perhaps or deliberately emphasise the implied insult as an illustration of the character of the speaker or the narrator.

But in general,  figurative use of an unfortunate disability is not pejorative to those with the disability.

For example, if an organisation needs to perform two functions to be successful, and I call it a one-legged organisation, then I am saying it is failing at one of the functions; I am not disparaging the morality of one-legged people.

Figurative use just recognises that the disability is not desirable. Most people would not choose to be schizophrenic, nor to lose a leg. I know I would not.

I am sure it is annoying for people to have their blameless condition used as a metaphor, but that can happen to us all. Just ask anyone named Karen.